# intellilj idea svn plugin: how to show last user who modified the file in the project tree view

Tags: java, svn, version-control, intellij-idea

when i am using the svn plugin in idea
it doesn't show who edited the file last time.
so i am wondering how to show the last user who modified the file (and also the modification time) in the project tree view, just like what myeclipse does

i am a newbie to intellij

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible to show directly in the project tree, but you can highlight the source file and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> to show subversion history.

The top record in the table tells you `Version`, `Date`, `Author`, `Commit Message`, etc.

p.s. welcome to IntelliJ! Have you downloaded the keymap cheat sheet? it's very useful :)